# Ruby and PostgreSQL text matching

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am trying to do some text matching in Ruby using PostgreSQL.

This is my code:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'
require 'pg'
require 'pry'

$config = '
adapter: postgresql
database: edgar
username: YYYYY
password:
host: 127.0.0.1'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load($config))
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base; end

#Searching database edgar and table for key words

#install gem install pg_search

class Filing < ActiveRecord:: Base
    include PgSearch
end


class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base
    pg_search_score:search_eightks,
    :against => [:cancer, heart attack] 
end
```

I have a few questions:

1. How do I search the *eightks* table of my database?
2. How do I search for multiple words? I want to see if a document contains the word "cancer" OR "heart attack". It doesn't need both, just one or the other.

This is what the list of relations in the database looks like:

```
edgar=# \d
                      List of relations
 Schema |         Name          |   Type   |      Owner       
--------+-----------------------+----------+------------------
 public | crsp_ccm_lookup       | table    | YYYY
 public | docs                  | table    | YYYY
 public | docs_downloaded       | table    | YYYY
 public | docs_id_seq           | sequence | YYYY
 public | document_types        | table    | YYYY
 public | document_types_id_seq | sequence | YYYY
 public | eightks               | table    | YYYY
 public | filings               | table    | YYYY
 public | filings_for_run       | table    | YYYY
 public | filings_id_seq1       | sequence | YYYY
 public | indices               | table    | YYYY
 public | indices_id_seq        | sequence | YYYY
 public | scraper_groups        | table    | YYYY
 public | scraper_groups_id_seq | sequence | YYYY
 public | ws                    | view     | YYYY
 public | ws_table              | table    | YYYY
 public | z_docs_10_ks          | table    | YYYY
(17 rows)
```

Ideally when a text document containing these words is found I would like to COPY it to a new folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't create globals like `$config` unless you understand why you need a global, which is pretty rare. Using them hints at variable-scope smell and a lack of understanding how variables work in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things regarding the code above specifically:

1. Not quite sure why you're opening the class twice in a row (and also a third time above that)
2. I believe `pg_search_scope` (note the `p` instead of `r`) is the correct term to use (I don't see `pg_search_score` in the code for [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search))

So something like this:

```
class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PgSearch

    pg_search_scope:search_eightks,
    :against => [:cancer, heart attack] 
end
```

However, I am wondering if you really want to use full text search here, as that is a reasonably niche use case for *Postgres*.

For example, if the docs are just of type `text`, you could run a regex against them to check (or one of the string functions). Now, if they're large documents, or if you wanted to do some more advanced things like ranking the search results (in a somewhat *Solr* like fashion), then full-text may be worth a look.

What is the overall picture of what you're trying to accomplish here? (Not how, but what/why?) Will also need more info as to what the definitions of the tables involved are, and also what version of *Postgres*.

Also, not quite sure what you mean by *copy it to a new folder*. *folder* doesn't mean anything in *Postgres*. Are you mixing *Postgres* terms with terms from your application logic?

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Based on your comments about there being 200,000 documents (which sounds like a fairly small dataset, unless the documents themselves are absolutely enormous), and you wanting to check to see if there are a few keywords contained in them, assuming the documents are text (which it sounds like they are) I would recommend using a *Postgres* regex.

Assuming, for the sake of an example, that the document text is stored in a column called `contents` in the `docs` table, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM docs
WHERE contents ~* 'heart attack|cancer|illness';
```

*ActiveRecord* lets you use raw SQL via the `connection.execute` method, where you would pass the above query as a string.

You can then process them further as desired.

I'm not saying you won't ever need to use full text search for this sort of thing, it's just that I wouldn't recommend starting with that, especially based on the information you've provided regarding your use case and data.

**Edit in response to follow-up comment from OP:**

The code you said you were using:

```
require
    Select * from eightks where contents ~* 'heart attack | cancer |illness'
end
```

is not valid *Ruby*. You would need a `begin` to go with the `end`, instead of the `require`, and the SQL needs to be a string which is passed to your *Active Record* object's `connection.execute` method. There doesn't appear to be a connection object listed in your code above. Possibly, it would be an instance of the *Filing* class you're defining.

Also, the column `contents` will only work if you actually have that in your table definition. That was just for the example -- you'll need to adapt it to fit your specific table.

If you have additional issues getting the raw *SQL* to work in your scenario, it should be split off into a separate question, as this one is getting pretty long and veering into separate (although related) issues. You can link this question for additional context.

Comment: Hi @Ken_Hampson.. thanks so much for your detailed reply. I have around 200,000 text documents. I am trying to see whether these documents contain a list of certain words. For example, does the document mention cancer, heart attack, illness. Once a document containing any of these words is found I want to know which document it is so I can examine it further. I am only using Pg_search because i came across it on another discussion forum. Sorry for being so new to this.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I will add a bit to my answer above.

Comment: Hi @Ken_Hampson... thanks so much for your help. When i do that i receive the following error in my terminal  ruby edgar_demo.rb
edgar_demo.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
edgar_demo.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected *
 where contents ~* 'heart attack | cancer |illness'
                  ^
edgar_demo.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'. Not sure why? This is the code from my ruby require 


Select * from eightks
 where contents ~* 'heart attack | cancer |illness'
end